# Subtracting a comma separed string from another in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a default comma separated string:

```
test1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
```

And I have a dynamic variable `test2`, lets say:

```
test2 = "2,5,7";
```

I need a string which will not have values of `test2`. This means the result should be:

```
result = 1,3,4,6,8,9
```

Is there a built in function that can compare the two strings, or arrays, removing the contents of `test2` from `test1`?

Comment: Convert both string into array's and compare. You should try something on your own first

Comment: An assigment? What's the greater purpose? And last but not least - where is your attempt/code?

Comment: Can there be repeats in `test1` and if so, do they need to be present in the output string?

Comment: @SeanVieira no test1 is a constant string with no repeats.

Comment: come back when you have some code for this  and need extra help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this with a quick search, maybe you could adjust it to suit your needs.

Before you ask questions like this, make sure you've a had good search before hand and then try and get it working by yourself. If you fail, then ask questions how to finish what you started and provide some code - then more people will be willing to help you. I found this and adjusted it to your spec in less than 3-minutes.

```
var a = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
var b = [ '1', '2' ];

var minus = function ( a, b ) {
    return a.filter(function ( name ) {
        return b.indexOf( name ) === -1;
    });
};            

var result = minus( a, b );

document.write( result ); // returns 3
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SjF9p/7/) test.